# Parse Server Image Upload Error 101

Tags: objective-c, macos, heroku, parse-server, mlab

Parse Server issues.

I have a class (mongo collection) on Parse server, data all there, columns all there.  I have a column for file, which holds an image. I have an osx app which I used to use to upload the images to this column on parse.com - I made the necessary changes to the osx app to point it at my heroku/mlab database, which it can see. When I tried to upload the first image, I got an error: `[Error]: No results matched the query. (Code: 101, Version: 1.14.2)`

The method is that I have a Plist that matches the class that the app searches for file name, queries parse for the row, gets the objectId, and then uploads the corresponding file to the row.  Using NSlogs I can see that the app has found the right objectId, so it has found all it needs to - but it errors.

So the next thought, try manually uploading the image file on parse dashboard.  Presents an error in the log: `Error generating response. ParseError { code: 101, message: 'Object not found.' }`

Bit baffled about this 101 error - I know it's finding the object correctly as the objectId's aren't listed in the plist, so it wouldn't be able to display it in NSLog if it wasn't finding the object in the db.  Also, I'm getting the same error when trying to upload directly via dashboard.

Any thoughts anyone?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some code? did you configure some storage adapters or you are using the default one (file system storage)? did you check that the column of the image is of type ParseFile ?

Comment: I tried changing the column type in _SCHEMA to ParseFile and it messed up the class - all the columns disappeared.  When I create a column using dashboard it just calls it `"parseManufacturerImage": "file",`.    If I create a row in the same class on dashboard, I can add an image manually via dashboard.  If I use mongochef to import a csv and try to edit any field on parse dashboard i get the `Error generating response. ParseError { code: 101, message: 'Object not found.' }`  - can you shine any light on how to use mongoimport to import to a remote host?  I struggled to get the command right.

Comment: ...continuing that, if I've imported a csv with mongochef, I can't edit any of the rows i've imported.  If i create another row via the dashboard, I can edit and upload to it.  I know I've not shown any code, but as I'm getting the same error with dashboard and the code worked fine for parse.com, I don''t 'think' it's that.

Comment: cancel that. figured out mongoimport, didn't work.  Think I'm going to have to rewrite the upload app to upload all rows so they're being created by parse, and create the class and columns  manually.  Is there a way to create a column in objective-c so I can do that programatically?